How to ignore and hide certain console warning in Playwright UI
When I run tests on our web app in the Playwright UI, the console gets completely cluttered by this message:
"Third-party cookie will be blocked. Learn more in the Issues tab."
I am aware that this comes from the website, but it makes it hard to see the console messages I DO want to see.
Is there a way to filter this message out in the Playwright UI or at least aggregate them into a single line?


You may filter the unwanted warning messages:
// Listen for all console events and filter the ones not required:
page.on('console', msg => {
  if (msg.text() !== 'filter me,I am ANNOYING!!!')
    console.log(`Msg text: "${msg.text()}"`);
});


Thank you for your hint. Unfortunately this does not work. This logs the messages that are not the unwanted message double. I still see all the original console messages.

It's simply filtering based on message text .
